# Polynomials $P(x)\in k[x]$ satisfying condition $P(x^2)=P(-x)P(x)$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, functional-equations

Fix a field $k$.  Let $P(x)\in k[x]$ be such that $$(1)\ \ \ \ \ P(x^2)=P(-x)P(x).$$
Let $T(k,d)\subseteq k[x]$ denote the set of solutions to $(1)$ of degree $d$, and $t(k,d)=\big|T(k,d)\big|$.  Constant solutions are obviously $P\equiv 0$ and $P\equiv 1$.  So $T(k,0)=\{0,1\}$ and $t(k,0)=2$.  We assume from now on that $d>0$, so $P(x)$ is non-constant.

> ***Questions:***  (a) Is it possible to list all elements of $T(k,d)$?   (b) How to calculate $t(k,d)$?  (If this is too broad, we can take $k$ to be $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.)

Here is my attempt.  If $z\in \overline{k}$ is a root of $P(x)$, then $z^{2^n}$ is a root of $P(x)$ for every $n$.  Since $P$ has finitely many roots, we must have $z=0$ or $z^{2^n-1}=1$ for some positive integer $n$.  Suppose that $0$ is a root of $P(x)$ of multiplicity $m_0$.  Then, $P(x)=x^{m_0}P_1(x)$ for some $P_1(x)\in k[x]$ such that $P_1(0)\neq 0$.   Using $(1)$ we get
$$(2)\ \ \ \ \ P_1(x^2)=(-1)^{m_0}P_1(-x)P_1(x).$$

Let $m_1$ be the smallest positive integer such that $P_1(x)$ has a root $w_1\in\overline k$ such that $w_1^{2^{m_1}-1}=1$.  Because $m_1$ is the smallest possible, $w_1$, $w_1^2$, $w_1^{2^2}$, $\ldots$, $w_1^{2^{m_1-1}}$ are pairwise distinct roots of $P_1(x)$.  This shows that
$$P_1(x)=\prod_{r=0}^{m_1-1}\left(x-w_1^{2^r}\right)P_2(x),$$
where $P_2(x)\in\overline{k}[x]$ satisfies
$$P_2(x^2)=(-1)^{m_0+m_1}P_2(-x)P_2(x).$$

In the end, we can use induction to show that there exist integers $m_0\geq 0$, $m_1>0$, $m_2>0$, $\dots$, $m_l>0$ such that
$$(3)\ \ \ \ \ P(x)=(-1)^d\,x^{m_0}\,W_1(x)\,W_2(x)\,\cdots\,W_l(x)\,,$$
where $m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_l=d$ and each $W_j(x)\in \overline{k}[x]$ is of the form
$$\prod_{r=0}^{m_j-1}\,\left(x-w_j^{2^{r}}\right)\,,$$
where each $w_j\in\overline{k}$ is a root of $z^{2^{m_j}-1}-1$, but not a root of $z^{2^r-1}=1$ for any positive integer $r<m_j$.  If $k$ is algebraically closed then $(3)$ is as good a description as you can get, I guess.  But what happens when $k$ is not algebraically closed?

In particular, if $d=4$ and $k=\Bbb C$, there are the following possible choices:

1. $P(x)=x^4$
2. $P(x)=x^3\,(x-1)$
3. $P(x)=x^2\,(x-1)^2$
4. $P(x)=x^2\,(x^2+x+1)$
5. $P(x)=x\,(x-1)^3$
6. $P(x)=x\,(x-1)\,(x^2+x+1)$
7. $P(x)=x\,\prod\limits_{r=0}^2\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{7}\right)\Bigg)$
8. $P(x)=x\,\prod\limits_{r=0}^2\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{7}\right)\Bigg)$
9. $P(x)=(x-1)^4$
10. $P(x)=(x-1)^2\,(x^2+x+1)$
11. $P(x)=(x-1)\,\prod\limits_{r=0}^2\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{7}\right)\Bigg)$
12. $P(x)=(x-1)\,\prod\limits_{r=0}^2\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{7}\right)\Bigg)$
13. $P(x)=(x^2+x+1)^2$
14. $P(x)=\prod\limits_{r=0}^3\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{15}\right)\Bigg)$
15. $P(x)=\prod\limits_{r=0}^3\,\Bigg(x-\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi {2^r} i}{15}\right)\Bigg)$
16. $P(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Unless I omitted something, this gives $t(\Bbb C,4)=16$.  Furthermore, only polynomials 1-6, 9-10, 13, 16 have real coefficients (in fact rationals), $t(\Bbb R,4)= t(\Bbb Q,4)=10$.

Comment: I don't think it follows that "*we must have $z=0$ or $z^{2^n-1}=1$ for some positive integer $n$*". Since $P$ has finitely many roots, we must have $j,k>j$ such that $z^{2^j} = z^{2^k}$, so either $z^{2^j} = 0$ or $1 = z^{2^k-2^j} = z^{2^j(2^{k-j} - 1)}$. Now, every odd number $c$ satisfies $2^{\varphi(c)} \equiv 1 \pmod c$. Every integer $n$ can be written as $n=2^mc$ with odd $c$. Then $n$ is a factor of $2^m (2^{\varphi(c)} - 1)$, so setting $j=m$ and $k=m+\varphi(c)$ we haven't shown anything stronger than that $z$ must be zero or a root of unity.

Comment: @PeterTaylor  You are right, but the thing is, if $z$ is a root of $P(x)$, so $\tilde{z}:=z^{2^j}$ is a root such that $\tilde{z}^{2^{k-j}-1}=1$.  In a sense, Snookie's statement is not entirely correct, but it is not very wrong either.

Comment: @Batominovski, I'd just come to a similar conclusion from a different direction. Essentially, by pairing we must have cycles rather than rhos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If $z\in \overline{k}$ is a root of $P(x)$, then $z^{2^m}$ is a root of $P(x)$ for every $m$.  Since $P$ has finitely many roots, we must have $z=0$ or $z^{2^n-1}=1$ for some positive integer $n$.

As I previously mentioned in a comment, I think this argument could do with filling a gap, so I'll start from scratch.

---

$P(x) \in K[x]$ of degree $d$ satisfies $P(x^2) = P(x)P(-x)$. If we lift to the splitting field of $P$ over $K$, $P(x) = a_d \prod_{i=1}^d (x - \alpha_i)$. By the functional equation, $P(x) = (-1)^d a_d^2 \prod_{i=1}^d (x - \alpha_i^2)$. When $d=0$ we have the exceptional solution $P(x) = 0$; if $P(x)$ is non-zero then $a_d = (-1)^d$ and $\{\alpha_i\} = \{\alpha_i^2\}$ taken as multisets. Therefore there is a permutation $\pi$ for which $\alpha_i^2 = \alpha_{\pi(i)}$. If $i$ is in a cycle of length $n_i$ in $\pi$ then $\alpha^{2^{n_i}} = \alpha_i$, so $\alpha_i = 0$ or $\alpha_i^{2^{n_i}-1} = 1$. If $\alpha_i$ is a non-zero root, it's an odd power of unity, and so there is an odd $m_i$ for which it's a primitive $m_i$th root of unity. Then its minimum cycle length is the multiplicative order of $2 \bmod m_i$, which I will denote $\textrm{ord}_{m_i}(2)$ (or [A002326](//oeis.org/)$(\frac{m_i-1}{2})$).

If $\alpha_i \in K$ then that cycle of $\textrm{ord}_{m_i}(2)$ roots does not imply the presence of any other roots. However, if $\alpha_i \not\in K$ then each of the roots in the cycle requires its entire minimal polynomial over $K$, so we account for a factor of the LCM of their minimal polynomials. Therefore the key questions are about how the cyclotomic polynomials split: how many conjugates does each root have, and how many distinct minimal polynomials are covered by a cycle?

I'm not aware of any standard notation for these statistics, so let $c_K(m_i)$ be the number of conjugates of a primitive $m_i$th root of unity over $K$, and $\rho_K(m_i)$ be the number of distinct minimal polynomials covered by a cycle.

#### In general terms

Let $p$ be the characteristic of $K$. As shown in [Proof that there are exactly $n$ distinct $n$th roots of unity in fields of characteristic zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917312), there are no primitive $n$th roots of unity if $n$ is a multiple of $p$; otherwise there are exactly $\varphi(n)$ (distinct) primitive $n$th roots of unity. (Note that in consequence for characteristic $2$ we don't lose any odd-power primitive roots of unity relative to characteristic $0$).

If there are primitive $m_i$th roots of unity, each comes as part of a set of $c_K(m_i) \rho_K(m_i)$, so there are $\frac{\varphi(m_i)}{c_K(m_i) \rho_K(m_i)}$ such sets. Therefore the generating function for the number of building blocks of $P$ with degree $n$ is (including the exceptional building block of degree one, $\alpha_i = 0$) $$A_K(x) = x + \sum_{\substack{m \textrm{ odd},\\ p \nmid m}} \frac{\varphi(m)}{c_K(m_i) \rho_K(m_i)} x^{c_K(m_i) \rho_K(m_i)}$$
To get a generating function for $t(K,d)$, we take $A_K$'s Euler transform $B_K$ and add $1$ for the exceptional solution $P(x) = 0$.

#### $K$ is algebraically closed and has characteristic $0$ or $2$

E.g. $K = \mathbb{C}$. The cyclotomics split completely, so the minimal polynomials are linear and $c_K(m_i) = 1$ Obviously this means that $\rho(m_i) = \textrm{ord}_{m_i}(2)$.
$$A_{\mathbb{C}}(x) = x + \sum_{m \textrm{ odd}} \frac{\varphi(m)}{\textrm{ord}_m(2)} x^{\textrm{ord}_m(2)}$$

$$\begin{matrix}
d & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
A_\mathbb{C} & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 18 & 30 & 56 & 99 & 186 & 335 \\
1 + B_\mathbb{C} & 2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 2048 & 4096
\end{matrix}$$

$A_\mathbb{C}(n)$ looks suspiciously like OEIS [A001037](//oeis.org/A001037), which is neatly explained by the description

> Number of degree-$n$ irreducible polynomials over GF(2)

OEIS also confirms that the Euler transform of A001037 is the powers of $2$, so the conjecture which jumps out from the table is in fact true.

#### $\mathbb{Q}$

The cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible, so $c_K(m_i) = \varphi(m_i)$ and $\rho(m_i) = 1$.
$$A_\mathbb{Q}(x) = x + \sum_{m \textrm{ odd}} x^{\varphi(m)}$$

$$\begin{matrix}
d & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
A_\mathbb{Q} & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 + B_\mathbb{Q} & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 14 & 22 & 30 & 44 & 58 & 81 & 104 & 143 
\end{matrix}$$

Obviously these are the two extremes (for characteristic zero). In between them we have fields where the cyclotomics split partially.

#### $\mathbb{R}$

The first two cyclotomic polynomials are linear; the rest split into quadratics over $\mathbb{R}$, pairing each complex root of unity with its conjugate, so $c_{\mathbb{R}}(m_i) = 1 + [m_i > 2]$. A cycle contains a root and its square iff $-1$ is a power of $2 \pmod{m_i}$, so $$\rho_{\mathbb{R}}(m_i) = \begin{cases} 1 & m_i = 1 \\ \frac12 \textrm{ord}_{m_i}(2) & 2^j \equiv -1 \pmod{m_i} \\ \textrm{ord}_{m_i}(2) & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

The first $m_i$ to diverge from the rational case is $m_i = 17$, which retains its two separate $8$-cycles, so the values obtained are closer to those for $\mathbb{Q}$ than for $\mathbb{R}$.

$$\begin{matrix}
d                & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 &  11 &  12 \\
A_\mathbb{R}     & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 &  1 &  0 &  2 &  0 &  3 &  0 &  6 &   0 &   9 \\
1 + B_\mathbb{R} & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 14 & 22 & 30 & 46 & 62 & 94 & 126 & 190
\end{matrix}$$

#### Finite fields

Consider $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q = p^a$ and $p$ is prime. Cribbing from [another MSE answer](/a/305123/5676),

> Let $z$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity in an extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $\mathbb{F}_q[z]=\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$. Because the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ is cyclic of order $q^k-1$, we know that $k$ is the smallest positive integer with the property that $n \mid q^k-1$. By the Galois theory of finite fields the minimal polynomial of $z$ is $$m(x)=(x-z)(x-z^q)(x-z^{q^2})\cdots(x-z^{q^{k-1}})$$

So if $\alpha$ is a primitive $n$th root, the elements of the cycle are $\alpha^{2^i}$ and the elements of the root set are $(\alpha^{2^i})^{q^j}$. Clearly characteristic $2$ is a special case, and $A_{\mathbb{F}_{2^a}} = A_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Rather than try to add a lot more tables to this answer for other prime characteristics, I've put some [code on Github to generate them](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/fb0ae043783f2e3e65c51746aaf9952e).