# In an algebraically closed field, does every nonzero element have n distinct n-th roots?

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field. This certainly implies that every non-zero element $x$ of $F$ has at least one $n$-th root, for each positive integer $n$. Does it in fact imply the condition that every non-zero element has $n$ distinct $n$-th roots?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917312/proof-that-there-are-exactly-n-distinct-nth-roots-of-unity-in-fields-of-char This seems to have some relevant info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that if $F$ is a field of characteristic $p,$ then $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p.$ How many distinct $p$th roots of unity does this imply are there in $F$?

**Hint:** What equation must a $p$th root of unity satisfy? Once you have this, apply the first hint.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe p distinct roots of unity? Just a guess

Comment: @user107952 See if the hint I've added helps you make progress!

Comment: I think it implies it has only one root.

Comment: @user107952 that's correct; $x^p - 1 = x^p - 1^p = (x - 1)^p,$ so there is only one distinct $p$th root of unity in any field of characteristic $p.$

Comment: What about the case of characteristic of zero? I think in that case, there would be n distinct n-th roots, because AFAIK all algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero are elementarily equivalent to the complex number field.

Comment: If the field is algebraically closed of characteristic 0, then there are indeed $n$ distinct $n$th roots of any nonzero element. See the link in Ryan Shesler's comment under your question for details. However, not all algebraically closed fields of characteristic 0 are equivalent to $\Bbb C$: you must assume the field has the same cardinality as $\Bbb C$ for this to be true.

Comment: The link discusses roots of unity in particular, but the ideas involving formal derivatives in the comments work more generally.